# Convert Column to JSON object of Another column in Azure Dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I have data in below format and i am using Data flow to format the record in JSON format and store it into another column of the Data.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSpNF.png)

Wanted to convert in below format using Dataflow:

[Output Format Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKSQu.png)

I am not getting any way to convert this using Data Flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use derived column transformations to achieve this. I have taken the following as my source.

[image]

- Now, make key value pair separately using `associate` function to create 2 new columns using derived column transformation.

```
A: associate(CUST_ID_A,{SCORE A})
B: associate(CUST_ID_B,{SCORE B})
```

[image]

- Now, create an array using the newly created so columns as `array(A,B)`.

[image]

- Now, in sink, I choose a JSON sink file and mapped only required columns as shown below:

[image]

- This will give the final data preview as shown in the below image which is the requirement.

[image]

- The following is the complete dataflow JSON:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn2"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          TRANS_ID as string,",
                "          CUST_ID_A as string,",
                "          {SCORE A} as string,",
                "          CUST_ID_B as string,",
                "          {SCORE B} as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(A = associate(CUST_ID_A,{SCORE A}),",
                "          B = associate(CUST_ID_B,{SCORE B})) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 derive(cust_conf = array(A,B)) ~> derivedColumn2",
                "derivedColumn2 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['op.json'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     mapColumn(",
                "          TRANS_ID,",
                "          cust_conf",
                "     ),",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to SINK it to the database table?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.